# How to make a rollback in functions with transactions annotation in case if save operation returns null?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

I use Spring Boot 5 and MongoDB in my project. When I save a user in users collection I also need to save authority of the user in another collection. In case if an error has happened and one of the items did not saved I have to rollback the operation to prevent the saving
of the another item in case if it saved.

For this purpose I use Transaction annotation above my create method:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    public AutoMapper autoMapper;

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final AdminUserRepository adminUserRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public SaveBuilderResponse create(UserDto newUser){

        AdminUser adminUser = autoMapper.map(newUser, AdminUser.class);
        User userToSave = autoMapper.map(newUser, User.class);

        AdminUser savedAdminUser = adminUserRepository.save(adminUser);
        User savedUser = userRepository.save(builderToSave);

        return new SaveUserResponse(savedUser);
    }
}
```

As you can see in function above I have two rows that saves items:

```
        AdminUser savedAdminUser = adminUserRepository.save(adminUser);
        User savedBuilder = userRepository.save(userToSave);
```

After the the row above executed I need to check that returned value not null and proceed. In case if savedAdminUser or savedBuilder variables is null I need to do a rollabck to prevent the saving operation of the another item in case if it saved.

My question is how can I do rollback in case if savedAdminUser or savedUser variables is null?

Comment: Throw an exception.

Comment: If you're using `@RequiredArgsConstructor` (good), don't use `@Autowired` fields. Just make your field `final` and it will work without any further configuration.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic thank you for the comment.
Can you please provide a post with an example?

Answer (score 0):

you used, `@Transactional` annotation can rollback in case if savedAdminUser or savedUser variables is null.  Also you Should throw an exception like below.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public SaveBuilderResponse create(UserDto newUser) throws Exception {
    try {
        AdminUser adminUser = autoMapper.map(newUser, AdminUser.class);
        User userToSave = autoMapper.map(newUser, User.class);

        AdminUser savedAdminUser = adminUserRepository.save(adminUser);
        User savedUser = userRepository.save(builderToSave);

        return new SaveUserResponse(savedUser);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: why would you wrap it a try catch if you only rethrow the exception? it's useless. Just leave it as it is. If any exception occurs, it will have the same effect. You don't need to make a checked exception out of this.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to engage with custom exception you can simply do (before the last return statement)  :

```
if (adminUser == null || savedBuilder == null) {
   //do whatever you want
   return null; 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, is I return null is rollback will occur?
I think to trigger rollback exception should be thrown.
Do I right?

Comment: I don't sure I get the mean of rollback. What exactly you want to achieve? To remove from the DB another record that already saved, or to prevent future saving ? Maybe show your code.

Comment: But in any case you can achieve throwing behavior by if-else. But in fact if it's excepted it's more make sense to use try-catch behavior.